# Why arent my site posts appearing on search results anymore?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search

So i have this website-www.listen2science.com, a few days back i installed a plugin called seo for wordpress and posts of my site appeared on the top pages of google, but now even if i copy the whole of the title and search it doesnt appear in any result. Why is it happening? Also my site index on webmasters is zero still when i search for site:listen2science.com all my posts appear. And also if i search for my domain mine is the first result that comes so it turns out my site isnt blacklisted. I cant implement seo due to this, please help guys!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your site is fairly new.  Your earliest posts appear to be from October 2012.  When a site is less than a year old, it takes a while for Google to start trusting it.  There isn't anything technical wrong that I could find from the quick checks that I did.  Your canonical tags look correct, there is no problem with your robots.txt file.

While you are waiting for Google to trust your site you can do the following:

- Check who links to you.  Make sure there aren't spammy links there.  Certainly don't start spamming web forums with links to your site.
- Run a spider against your own site to make sure that it can be crawled in a manner similar to Googlebot.  I tend to use wget (a command line program), but there are Windows GUI crawlers available like Xenu Link Sleuth.
- Look through your server logs for problem such as unexpected error statuses.
- Check your analytics for anything out of the ordinary
- Make sure your wordpress is up to date.

Other than than, it may take a few months for your site to gain the trust that it needs to rank consistently.